# Video background and transparent overlay div (Safari and mobile issue)

Tags: css, html, video, overlay

I've been working on this page for a client: 
http://welcome.babbel.com/en/learn_spanish/

They want the very trendy look of a video + opaque div overlay, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work out on Safari. It seems the video refuses to respond to z-index, and the layering doesn't work. (on mobile, too). Oddly my research doesn't seem to be helping either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add relevant code, not just a link.